# OpenZeppelin import problem

Tags: openzeppelin, import, safemath

I am trying to import a couple of OpenZeppelin contracts to my project, but each time I am given an error related to unsuccessful imports from sources. I'm gonna attach a screenshot of my code. I have to mention that I am using Macos and I have installed NPM package of OpenZeppelin via terminal, although it's not visible in my node_modules folder. Could anyone help me with a proper way of importing OpenZeppeli contracts on Remix?
Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to importing OpenZeppelin contracts in Remix IDE:

1. Copy and paste.
2. Import with github links.

So if you write:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

That should be fine.

Comment: My pleasure. Can you mark my answer as correct?